# Disable undertow from jboss EAP 7

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

Is there any way to disable 'undertow' web container when starting up the Jboss? 
it was there in

> standalone.xml

as a subsystem , but removing from there will not disable undertow.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain your use case better?

Comment: Undertow is the servlet container. What is it you don't want to use?

Comment: @stdunbar -thank you for your respond, i will use good old tomcat as my webserver and i only need to deploy my EJBs in jboss. So as a user I don't want to startup undertow bt only jboss.

Comment: @James R. Perkins- thank u james, as i explained above it will be unneccsary to keep undertow up and running in my case and i am looking for a toggle switch to enable / disable undertow from my app server.

Comment: If you disable undertow EJB's likely won't work. I don't see any benefit in disabling Undertow. WildFly is not a standalone EJB container.

Comment: @james - Thank you very much for the info james. I thought WildFly will handle EJB stuff alone. So to keep unwanted listeners turend off i thought of disabling Undertow.

Comment: A lot of Java EE API's required the servlet API. It's really the base of any Java EE container.